# Why can't I center a table generated with tabularray?

Tags: tabularray

I've tried to center this table but for some reason \centering and the center environment do not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% times clone
\begin{document}
\section*{Anexos}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}% use comma separator

\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Valores do estudo espetrofotométrico das duas cromatografias}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {c
    S[table-format={1.3}]
    S[table-format={1.3}]
    S[table-format={1.3}]},
    rows = {belowsep=0pt},% narrower rows
    row{even[3-Z]} = {black!6}% even rows from 3 on are gray
}
\toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}{{{V\\(mL)}}}
&
{{{1\textsuperscript{a}\\ Cromatografia}}}
&
\SetCell[c=2]{c}{{{2\textsuperscript{a} \\ Cromatografia}}}
& \\ \midrule{2-5}
& {{{Abs\\(620 nm)}}} & {{{Abs\\(280 nm)}}} & {{{Abs\\(410 nm)}}} \\
\midrule
1  & 0,001  & 0,000      & 0,000 \\
2  & 0,000     & 0,000      & 0,000 \\
3  & -0,001 & 0,000      & 0,000 \\
4  & -0,003 & -0,001 & -0,002 \\
5  & 0,000      & -0,001 & 0,000 \\
6  & 0,001  & -0,001 & -0,001 \\
7  & 0,03   & -0,001 & -0,002 \\
8  & 0,174  & 0,048  & 0,009 \\
9  & 0,109  & 0,119  & 0,02 \\
10 & 0,032  & 0,155  & 0,034 \\
11 & 0,005  & 0,144  & 0,063 \\
12 & 0,000      & 0,118  & 0,128 \\
13 & -0,002 & 0,113  & 0,254 \\
14 & -0,003 & 0,134  & 0,437 \\
15 & -0,003 & 0,155  & 0,589 \\
16 & -0,004 & 0,184  & 0,716 \\
17 & -0,004 & 0,159  & 0,652 \\
18 & -0,001 & 0,131  & 0,538 \\
19 &        & 0,133  & 0,405 \\
20 &        & 0,247  & 0,281 \\
21 &        & 0,568  & 0,289 \\
22 &        & 0,941  & 0,324 \\
23 &        & 1,076  & 0,317 \\
24 &        & 1,363  & 0,379 \\
25 &        & 0,796  & 0,219 \\
26 &        & 0,449  & 0,124 \\
27 &        & 0,239  & 0,063 \\
28 &        & 0,130   & 0,037 \\
29 &        & 0,056  & 0,018 \\
30 &        & 0,024  & 0,008 \\
31 &        & 0,005  & 0,002 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `table` is a floating environment, you should not put it inside `center`. Use `\centering` inside `table` (though in this case you should do `\centering\arraybackslash`) for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `\centering` right after `\begin{table}` and the table will be centred.

I removed `adjustbox` because it is unnecessary. `tabularray` has its own way to adjust width. I'd also consider using `X`-type as one of the columns if a table has fixed width.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% times clone


\begin{document}
\section*{Anexos}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}% use comma separator

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Valores do estudo espetrofotométrico das duas cromatografias}
  \begin{tblr}{
      width = 0.45\textwidth,
      colspec = {X
        S[table-format={1.3}]
        S[table-format={1.3}]
        S[table-format={1.3}]
      },
      rows = {belowsep=0pt},% narrower rows
      row{even[3-Z]} = {black!6}% even rows from 3 on are gray
    }
    \toprule
    \SetCell[r=2]{c}{{{V\\(mL)}}}
    &
    {{{1\textsuperscript{a}\\ Cromatografia}}}
    &
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}{{{2\textsuperscript{a} \\ Cromatografia}}}
    & \\ \midrule{2-5}
    & {{{Abs\\(620 nm)}}} & {{{Abs\\(280 nm)}}} & {{{Abs\\(410 nm)}}} \\
    \midrule
    1  & 0,001  & 0,000      & 0,000 \\
    2  & 0,000     & 0,000      & 0,000 \\
    3  & -0,001 & 0,000      & 0,000 \\
    4  & -0,003 & -0,001 & -0,002 \\
    5  & 0,000      & -0,001 & 0,000 \\
    6  & 0,001  & -0,001 & -0,001 \\
    7  & 0,03   & -0,001 & -0,002 \\
    8  & 0,174  & 0,048  & 0,009 \\
    9  & 0,109  & 0,119  & 0,02 \\
    10 & 0,032  & 0,155  & 0,034 \\
    11 & 0,005  & 0,144  & 0,063 \\
    12 & 0,000      & 0,118  & 0,128 \\
    13 & -0,002 & 0,113  & 0,254 \\
    14 & -0,003 & 0,134  & 0,437 \\
    15 & -0,003 & 0,155  & 0,589 \\
    16 & -0,004 & 0,184  & 0,716 \\
    17 & -0,004 & 0,159  & 0,652 \\
    18 & -0,001 & 0,131  & 0,538 \\
    19 &        & 0,133  & 0,405 \\
    20 &        & 0,247  & 0,281 \\
    21 &        & 0,568  & 0,289 \\
    22 &        & 0,941  & 0,324 \\
    23 &        & 1,076  & 0,317 \\
    24 &        & 1,363  & 0,379 \\
    25 &        & 0,796  & 0,219 \\
    26 &        & 0,449  & 0,124 \\
    27 &        & 0,239  & 0,063 \\
    28 &        & 0,130   & 0,037 \\
    29 &        & 0,056  & 0,018 \\
    30 &        & 0,024  & 0,008 \\
    31 &        & 0,005  & 0,002 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of nice @Celdor answer (+1):

- table placement option is changes to `[!ht]`
- for first two rows are used option `guard˙ (available with` tabularray` version 2022A)
- all column are variations of `s` columns
- in `S` formating of `S` columns are consider minus sign
  removed are "zebras", inste4ad it rows are grouped in pair with reduced vertical separations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}% use comma separator

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% times clone


\begin{document}
\section*{Anexos}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Valores do estudo espetrofotométrico das duas cromatografias}
  \begin{tblr}{ width = 0.5\linewidth,
                colspec = { X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                            *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]} },
                row{1,2} = {guard},
                row{odd[3-Y]} = {belowsep=-3pt}% even rows from 3 on are gray
            }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    {V\\(mL)}   
    &   {1\textsuperscript{a}\\ Cromatografia}
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {2\textsuperscript{a}\\ Cromatografia}
            &                                        \\ 
    \cmidrule[r=-0.4]{2-2} \cmidrule[l=-0.4]{3-4}
    &   {Abs\\(\qty{620}{\nano\meter})}
        &   {Abs\\(\qty{280}{\nano\meter})}
            &   {Abs\\(\qty{410}{\nano\meter})}     \\
    \midrule
1  & 0,001  & 0,000  & 0,000 \\
2  & 0,000  & 0,000  & 0,000 \\
3  & -0,001 & 0,000  & 0,000 \\
4  & -0,003 & -0,001 & -0,002 \\
5  & 0,000  & -0,001 & 0,000 \\
6  & 0,001  & -0,001 & -0,001 \\
7  & 0,03   & -0,001 & -0,002 \\
8  & 0,174  & 0,048  & 0,009 \\
9  & 0,109  & 0,119  & 0,02 \\
10 & 0,032  & 0,155  & 0,034 \\
11 & 0,005  & 0,144  & 0,063 \\
12 & 0,000  & 0,118  & 0,128 \\
13 & -0,002 & 0,113  & 0,254 \\
14 & -0,003 & 0,134  & 0,437 \\
15 & -0,003 & 0,155  & 0,589 \\
16 & -0,004 & 0,184  & 0,716 \\
17 & -0,004 & 0,159  & 0,652 \\
18 & -0,001 & 0,131  & 0,538 \\
19 &        & 0,133  & 0,405 \\
20 &        & 0,247  & 0,281 \\
21 &        & 0,568  & 0,289 \\
22 &        & 0,941  & 0,324 \\
23 &        & 1,076  & 0,317 \\
24 &        & 1,363  & 0,379 \\
25 &        & 0,796  & 0,219 \\
26 &        & 0,449  & 0,124 \\
27 &        & 0,239  & 0,063 \\
28 &        & 0,130  & 0,037 \\
29 &        & 0,056  & 0,018 \\
30 &        & 0,024  & 0,008 \\
31 &        & 0,005  & 0,002 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have merely added `\centering` in right place. The changes here are concrete improvements!